# SOAP vs REST Webservice for realtime systems

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, real-time

Which type of a web service is the best one for realtime systems?
My application server is meant to provide information to clients at all times and as fast as possible and I'v found that the best way to do this is by setting up a web service to communicate with the clients.
My system is a "Real-Time" System and realiability, scalability and fast-responses are most crutial.

I will appreciate any advises or help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming if you're doing real-time data updates the data is small (either deltas or small data in general).

SOAP services have a larger amount of overhead than REST services.  The SOAP envelope alone might be larger than the size of the data it contains.

I prefer REST services mainly for this reason; they can be lightweight and efficient compared to SOAP-based services.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Just look into SOAP and REST examples you will see that SOAP is much more verbose than REST.

Comment: I did look into SOAP and REST and I came across an article in which it says that the SOAP format provides message-reliability and can handle several kinds of transmission failiure. Can any of you comment about this matter?